# How to call the parameters like room_height and wall_width etc in class RoomProperties?

Tags: python

If I donot use operator, how to call the parameters like room_height and wall_width etc in class RoomProperties? Also how to change the default value of the properties by python?

```
class RoomProperties():
    room_height: FloatProperty(
            name='Height', min=0.001, max=50,
            default=2.4, precision=3,
            description='Room height', update=update_room,
            )
    wall_width: FloatProperty(
            name='Thickness', min=0.000, max=10,
            default=0.0, precision=3,
            description='Thickness of the walls', update=update_room,
            )
    inverse: BoolProperty(
            name="Inverse", description="Inverse normals to outside",
            default=False,
            update=update_room,
            )
    crt_mat: BoolProperty(
            name="Create default Cycles materials",
            description="Create default materials for Cycles render",
            default=True,
            update=update_room,
            )
.....
}
```

Comment: Look in code for a pointer property (or collection) that uses that class eg `bpy.types.Object.foo = PointerProperty(type=RoomProperties)`  This would mean that `context.object.foo.wall_width = 1.0` could be set.  It could however be used in an operator... don't know haven't looked. Please add anything you find to question (or answer)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!